# Внешние шрифты или сделать их внутри проекта ? HTML

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

В общем разрабатываю небольшой сайтик и вначале я просто установил внешнее подключение шрифтов из google fonts
Сайт приближается к концу разработки и возник такой вопрос, а стоит ли переносить все внутрь папки с сайтом?
Кто что думает на этот счет?
Вот что у меня на данный момент

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Главная страница</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/styles.css">
```

Comment: Если загрузка gfonts не тормозит у вас ничего - используйте. Он анализирует ваши "запросы" и выдаёт нужный вам шрифт под браузер и т.п., это не просто "инклуд" файла, это "умный" инструмент.

Comment: @InDevX , нет это как раз таки просто подключение файла стилей. А вот правильно оформленное правило `@font-face` в файле - это инструмент, который выдаёт нужный файл под браузер и начертание шрифта

Comment: Так этот @font-face вам как-раз и отдают гуго шрифты.. Они сами считывают ваш клиент и отдают вам только нужные шрифты, вам только 1 строку прописать... Под _просто подключением файла стилей_ другое имелось ввиду...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, сервера то всё-таки Гугловские, а не абы чьи, доверять им можно. Да и с учётом того, что на один запрос пользователя всё будет идти в кэш и потом будет грузиться оттуда, то думаю, что грузить всё к себе на сервер не особо имеет смысл. Видел очень много сайтов, которые JQuery с серверов разрабов грузят и вообще не парятся)